# SQL Server generic way to update lastModified date per row

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I need to add a lastUpdatedDT column to all the tables in our SQL Server database.  The value should be the dateTime of the update for that row.

I have a SQL script that runs on deployment and adds the column to any table that does not have it.  My problem is how to update this value.

My first thought is a trigger, but I need a generic trigger body that I can add to every table with this column.

For the trigger to work I need to join the inserted pseudo table back to the real table.

```
update myTable
set lastUpdateDT = getDate()
where id = inserted.id
```

This will not work with a generic trigger body.  I need to know the name of the table and the primary key.  These could be different for every table.

I have tried:

```
inserted.lastUpdateDT = getDate()
```

but that does not work.

I do not have to use a trigger but I don't want to do something custom for every table.  Some developers will forget or screw it up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Triggers are NOT generic. They are created on individual tables. You will have to add a trigger on each table and yes you will have to know the name. You could leverage some dynamic sql to generate the trigger code but honestly a trigger on every table is an indication that something is off center.

Comment: If you are trying to prevent accidentally forgetting this column in an update this is an indication you should be using procedures for your updates. Then this problem fixes itself because your date logic will be in your update procedure.

Comment: You are in trouble here... I don't think there is any way for any sql database to update automatically a modifiedDate column without a trigger (by table). If it was createdDate that would be easier because you can just add a default value but on this case, you will need a trigger by table or modify the app to insert the modifiedDate column...

Comment: Sean Lange.  I understand how triggers work and did not imply one trigger would work for a all table.  I am just looking for a generic body.  Switching to a proc based approach several years into the project is not feasible.  It's frustrating to ask a question and get irrelevant comments.  I am not sure why you even commented.

Comment: I agree with asemprini.  I just wanted to check here before I abandoned the approach.